# javascript select iframe by id

Tags: javascript, iframe, jquery-selectors, selector

This cannot be impossible but i already spend quite some time looking for the answer here and trying combinations.

I have multiple iframes that are generated by code, every iframe has an unique id. I would like to be able to stop certain iframes from loading with a button or on doubleclick.

```
<iframe id='kwjef' src='kwjef.html'
   onClick="stop_iframe($(this).attr('id'));" />
<iframe id='wefhj' src='wefhj.html' 
   onClick="stop_iframe($(this).attr('id'));" />
<iframe id='yhvem' src='yhvem.html' 
   onClick="stop_iframe($(this).attr('id'));" />

function stop_iframe(id) {
  window.frames[0].stop(); /* works to stop first iframe */
  window.frames[1].stop(); /* works to stop second iframe */
  window.getElementById(id).stop(); /* throws error */
  $('iframe#'+id).stop(); /* throws error */
}
```

How can i select an iframe properly by id so that i can call the stop() ?

EDIT (thnxz Vicky Gonsalves):

```
function stop_iframe(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).src="#";
}
```

this works to blank the iframe but not to actually stop the request, the window.frames[0].stop(); does stop the request (like the stop button in your browser).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to stop, Just replace the src of iframe with `#` or `empty` URL:

```
function stop_iframe(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).src="#";
}
```

Comment: I forgot that in my initial post, this works to blank the iframe but not to actually stop the request, the `window.frames[0].stop();` does stop the request (like the stop button in your browser).